# Getting Error: Couldn't start the SPA development server with command 'npm start'. NPM is installed, npm.cmd is in ClientApp

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, entity-framework

Running VS 2022, React, have a React template project set up.

Here is enough of the error log from VS 2022 to describe what's happening:

```
'LPAAdmin.Web.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.1\System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'LPAAdmin.Web.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.1\System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Now listening on: http://localhost:5248
Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Hosting environment: Development
Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Content root path: D:\Clients\...\LPAAdmin\LPAAdmin.Web\
'LPAAdmin.Web.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.1\System.Net.Http.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'LPAAdmin.Web.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.1\System.Net.NameResolution.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy.SpaProxyLaunchManager: Information: No SPA development server running at http://localhost:44481 found.
'LPAAdmin.Web.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.1\System.Diagnostics.Process.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The thread 0x1730 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy.SpaProxyMiddleware: Information: SPA proxy is not ready. Returning temporary landing page.
```

I was getting an exception that npm.cmd could not be found in ClientApp folder.  So I copied a 2016 version to this folder from another project.

Since the npm.cmd can now be found, then the right path is being accessed.

If the error is right, that the SPA server can't be found on this port, then how does one start an SPA Server on a given port?

Comment: Jon, thanks for neatening this up :).  But ... do you know the answer :) LOL

Comment: For me it was my npm was outdated to run angular

Answer (score 1):

For me it was the node version (Mine was 16.2). I detected the problem when ran `npm run start` from ClientApp folder in the command prompt.

How I solved it:

- Installed nvm for having multiple node versions in separated environments on the same system (You can skip this step)

As mentioned my node version was 16.2 and didn't work (even if npm is telling in the log that minimum 14 or 16.10 is supported!)

- So, using nvm, I installed and used Node node 16.1 by doing `nvm install 16.1` removed node modules and rebuilt and run.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

using Powershell, go to the Client app and run the following command:
`npm run start`
then check the following processes:
In the visual studio solution go to .env.development.local and change:

SSL_CRT_FILE=C:\Users\administrator\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\https\file1.pem
SSL_KEY_FILE=C:\Users\administrator\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\https\file1.key

then run your asp-react app.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the npm.cmd file placed into ClientApp folder.

There were a couple steps needed to successfully install a React project.  A fellow developer knowledgeable with Angular helped solve this.

A different error now shows up but this is resolved.

Comment: Hi, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)